# How to change Managed Metadata top navigation width?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, metadata-navigation

currently I am preparing dynamic dropdown navigation in SharePoint Online using Managed Metadata function.

I have encountered an issue in classic view mode. 
When the term name is longer then 10-12 characters it places different word in  two or more lines (please see the example). 
[image]

I am looking for a solution to extend the menu width without creation of custom solution or modification of master page.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: This can be only achieved by changing appropriate styles. Which can be only achieved by modifying master page.. or you need to modify every page and manually add the CSS logic